# Trouble with String + RandBetween() VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
For i = i To nr_commercial
    Cells(i, 1) = commercial & RandBetween(1, 6)
Next i
```

Hi All - I have the above but I am not able to solve it. It returns a compiler error every time. I'm having issues putting a string plus a formula together.

`commercial` is defined as a string

I have even tried

```
Cells(i, 1) = commercial & = Randbetween(1,6)
```

and it returns error saying expecting expression. Is there something not right with the randbetween functionality?

I need to have output in cells such like:

```
commercial-1
commercial-5
commercial-3
```

Comment: Should `For i = i To nr_commercial` not be `For i = 1 To nr_commercial`? The problem is if `i` is 0 in `Cells(i, 1)`, then **this** will throw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.RANDBETWEEN(1,6)
```

For example:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim nr_commercial As Long, commercial As String

    nr_commercial = 10
    commercial = "whatever"
    For i = 1 To nr_commercial
        Cells(i, 1) = commercial & Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
    Next i
End Sub
```

*(also fixed the loop index)*

Comment: Thanks! I was playing around with the loops and must've left bad code before asking the question. But this works as intended! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
For i = i To nr_commercial
  Cells(i, 1) = "commercial-" & Application.WorksheetFunction.RANDBETWEEN(1,6)
Next i
```

Edited : `Application.WorksheetFunction.RANDBETWEEN(1,6)` is the correct formula to be used

Also it is not advisable to use `Cells` try to use `Sheet` or `Worksheet` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are using `For i = i To nr_commercial` which means every iteration it is changing "For 1 = 1 to nr_commercial" and then "2 = 2 to nr_commercial" which doesn't make sense. It should be `For i = 1 to nr_commercial` or whatever cell you want to start at, probably not in the first cell, as you are likely to have headers.